# Office 365 API using LastModifiedTime in $filter results in no response from server

Tags: office365

Is it possible to fetch events from the calendar API based on LastModifiedTime ?

If I try to make a GET request like the following:

```
GET /EWS/OData/Me/Events?$filter=LastModifiedTime ge 2014-07-23T03:53:43.6372302Z HTTP/1.1
Host: outlook.office365.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The server never seems to respond and the request eventually times out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your question! You should be able to use DateTimeLastModified. Note that the property name is 'DateTimeLastModified'. Below should work fine..
...Odata/Me/Events?$filter=DateTimeLastModified%20ge%202014-10-24T03:53:43.6372302Z
Thanks,
Sabitha